# img tag is not displaying while taking images in javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In ths module i just want to make a flipbook(magazine)so im taking images in a javascript array but the images are not loading up, instead of an image ([object" htmlimageelement]="")is displaying. I don't understand what I am missing in my code.And i'm sure that directory for my images is correct.I think I am missing something in my javascript file.

Html:

```
<html>
    <head>      
        <title>Flipbook</title>     
        <link href="jqmodule.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jqmodule.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
        <script src="jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.booklet.latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
    </head>
    <body class="body_div">
        <div class="container">         
            <div class="main clearfix">
                <div class="custom_wrapper">
                    <h3>Flipbook</h3>
                    <div id="mybook" class="booklet"></div>             
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var heading=['background-size','Using transform and the transform functions','Audio','CSS 1, CSS 2.1, CSS3 ...','The benefits of CSS3'];
    var para = new Array();
    para[0] = new Image();
    para[0].src = 'images/1.jpg';
    para[1] = new Image();
    para[1].src = 'images/2.jpg';
    para[2] = new Image();
    para[2].src = 'images/3.jpg';
$(function() {  
    var str="";
    for(var i=0;i<para.length;i++)
    {
        str+="<div class=\"b-page-blank\"><h1>"+heading[i]+"</h1><img src="+para[i]+"/></div>";                                 
    }
    $('#mybook').html(str);
    $('#mybook').booklet({ name: "Booklet" });  
    $(".b-counter").click(function(){   
        if($(this).attr('id')==2||$(this).attr('id')==4)
        {           
            $("#mybook").booklet("next");           
        }
        if($(this).attr('id')==3||$(this).attr('id')==5)
        {           
            $("#mybook").booklet("prev");
        }       
    });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<img src="+para[i].src+"/>` instead of `<img src="+para[i]+"/>` ?

Comment: Yes it works without "/"

Answer (score 0):

I may try this way, cleaner and easier to debug,

```
var data = [
    {heading:'background-size',imageSrc:'/images/1.jpg'}, 
    {heading:'Using transform and the transform functions',imageSrc:'/images/2.jpg'}, 
    {heading:'Audio',imageSrc:'/images/3.jpg'}
    // ...
];

$(function() {  
    var str="";
    $.each(data,function(index,row){
        str+="<div class=\"b-page-blank\"><h1>"+row.heading+"</h1><img src=\""+row.imageSrc+"\" /></div>";                                 
    })
    $('#mybook').html(str);
    //... rest of yoru code
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Okay i'll try this and can you please explain what is the use of (\.....\) these colon in (class=\"b-page-blank\) ?

Comment: it actually escapes the `"` so the js compiler does not think the string ends.  you could also start the string with single quote , but I wanted to keep your code style,

Comment: $.each(data,function(index,row) what you doing here?

Comment: as you are using jQuery, it actually creates a for each loop for data object, where `index` is loop iterator and `row` is the actual item in data object. so you will have access to it's properties such as `heading`. remember the names here are example, you can name then anything you want.